# Building a ServiceNow Interactive Filter for String Fields (Tags)

Tags: servicenow

I have built several dashboards but have not been able to understand interactive filters fully. I need a filter for Tags on Demands on ServiceNow, but Tags are a string field. Any help with either an out of the box interactive filter or code would be helpful, thanks!

I have tried each of the out of the box interactive filter types, but none of these seem to work for a string field.